# Unable to configure my Docker container using intermediate_instructions and pid_one_command in Test Kitchen

Tags: docker, chef-infra, test-kitchen

The following .kitchen.yml file fails to configure my docker container with the required tools mentioned in intermediate_instructions. The pid_one_command also does not work as the container still loads with the bash shell

Any ideas what is wrong with the file?

```
driver:
  name: docker
  socket: tcp://localhost:2375
  binary: docker.exe
  chef_version: latest
  privileged: true

provisioner:
  name: chef_zero
  # You may wish to disable always updating cookbooks in CI or other testing environments.
  # For example:
  #   always_update_cookbooks: <%= !ENV['CI'] %>
  always_update_cookbooks: true

verifier:
  name: inspec

platforms:
  - name: ubuntu-16.04
    driver:
      image: ubuntu:16.04
      pid_one_command: /bin/systemd
      intermediate_instructions:
        - RUN /usr/bin/apt-get install -y lsof which initscripts net-tools

suites:
  - name: default
    run_list:
      - recipe[testy::default]
    verifier:
      inspec_tests:
        - test/smoke/default
    attributes:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying to use config options for `kitchen-dokken` with `kitchen-docker`. The two projects are unrelated.

Comment: I think you are right. The training video I was referring was using kitchen-dokken. Thanks!